# Can you use Skyrim Legendary Edition mods on the normal edition?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just figured out I had Skyrim in my Steam games. It's the 32-bit non-Legendary Edition Skyrim without any DLCs. Can I still use Legendary Edition mods on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**
Mods developed for the original Skyrim, with or without DLC, will work fine on the Legendary Edition, which is essentially the same thing, but provided as a complete set of the base game and all DLC (similar to a Game of the Year edition). Or:

- Whatever mod requires Skyrim - with or without any additional DLC - will work with Skyrim Legendary Edition.
- Whatever mod requires Skyrim Legendary Edition will only work for a version of Skyrim with all DLC installed.

Comment: Do note that LE mods will state they require LE. The majority of mods will not require LE.

Comment: @Corsaka Yes, but that just means they need Skyrim plus all official DLCs (Dawnguard, Hearthfire, and Dragonborn).